# Definition of a worldline

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, terminology, definition

In general relativity, I am confused about the formal definition of a worldline.

Let our spacetime be a smooth manifold $M$ (spacetime has further structure, but I don't think it affects my question.). I have seen a worldline defined as a curve
\begin{align}
\gamma : \mathbb{R} &\longrightarrow M\\
r &\longmapsto p.
\end{align}
I have also seen it defined as an embedding of a (1-dimensional smooth) manifold, call it $W$, into the spacetime:
\begin{align}
\phi: W &\longrightarrow M\\
q&\longmapsto \phi(q) = p.
\end{align}
This embedding definition also extends to strings/branes, whereas I don't think the curve definition does.

In the case of the curve, there is a $r\in\mathbb{R}$ associated to each point on the worldline in the spacetime. In the case of the embedding definition, there is a $q\in W$ associated to each point on the worldline in the spacetime. It's not obvious to me if this is somehow the same.

My question is are these definitions equivalent? If so, is there a way to make the underlying object the same?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is a 1-dimenisonal smooth manifold...

Comment: @mmeent Ok so if $\mathbb{R}$ is implicitly treated as a smooth manifold (I assume with the standard topology?), then $\gamma$ is an embedding?

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13155. The short answer is that yes, they are indeed equivalent.

Comment: @VincentThacker Thanks, so am I understanding correctly that in general, and certainly for higher dimensional object, the structure is that of an embedding, but in the 1-dimensional case, it can be simplified to a curve, which is structurally much more simple to deal with?

Comment: @Bedge Essentially yes.